# How do I send a signal to a child process?

Tags: go, signals

I'm having trouble sending a signal from a parent process and receiving it in the child process.

This is the code for the child process. It exits when it receives SIGINT.

```
// child.go
func main() {
    stop := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(stop, os.Interrupt)
    fmt.Println("started")

    <-stop
    fmt.Println("stopped")
}
```

This is the parent process. It starts `child.go`, sends SIGINT, then waits for it to exit.

```
// main.go
func main() {
    // Start child process
    cmd := exec.Command("go", "run", "child.go")
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    err := cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        _, _ = fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Start: " + err.Error())
        return
    }

    // Wait, then send signal
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 500)
    err = cmd.Process.Signal(os.Interrupt)
    if err != nil {
        _, _ = fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Signal: " + err.Error())
        return
    }

    // Wait for child process to finish
    err = cmd.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        _, _ = fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Wait: " + err.Error())
    }
    return
}
```

This code should print `started\nstopped` to show that it worked as expected, but it only prints `started` and hangs at `cmd.Wait()`, meaning the child process did not receive the signal.

When I run `go run child.go` it works fine, so I don't think the problem is with that file. I understand that `func (*Process) Signal` doesn't work on Windows; I am using Linux.

How can I fix the code so that the child process gets the signal sent by the parent process?

Comment: The child process isn't your program, it's the `go` command. Don't use `go run`.

Comment: @JimB I tried using `go run child.go` from the terminal and then sent it a signal and it worked. Does `exec.Command` somehow work differently?

Comment: For one thing, `exec.Command` isn't a shell. It does work the same from the shell however, so how did you test it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned by @JimB in the comments section, the `go run` is your problem.

`go run child.go` will compile `child` and execute it as it's own process. If you run a `ps` after `go run child.go`, you will see two processes running.

The process you are watching and signalling is the `go` executable, not the `child`.

Replace the `exec.Command("go", "run", "child.go")` with the compiled binary `exec.Command("child")`and it should work.