# Node child processes: why does .kill() not close a 'go run...' process, but will close it for a straight binary?

Tags: node.js, go, process

I have long running go application, that I want to run from a node process.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Running")
    http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)
}
```

I set up my child process in node like:

```js
async function application(){

    //const myProcess = exec("go run main.go"); 
    const myProcess = exec("./main"); 

    myProcess.stdout.on('data', (chunk) => {
        console.log(chunk);
    })
    
    return new Promise(res => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            myProcess.on("close", () => {
                console.log("close")
                res(); 
                
            }); 
            myProcess.on("exit", () => {
                console.log("exit")
            })

            myProcess.kill();
        }, 1000); 
    
    })
}
```

This all works fine if I'm running the compiled binary directly (`./main`).

I'll get an output of:

```
Running

exit
close
(process exits)
```

However if I try run with `go run main.go` my output is

```
Running

exit
(process continues)
```

Specifically what is happening here that the `go run` process will not close properly?

My understanding is that this is going to come down to the difference between 'close' and 'exit' events.

From [the documentation:](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#event-close)

> The 'close' event is emitted after a process has ended and the stdio streams of a child process have been closed. This is distinct from the 'exit' event, since multiple processes might share the same stdio streams. The 'close' event will always emit after 'exit' was already emitted, or 'error' if the child failed to spawn.

Ok, so maybe something about go run leaving a stdio stream open? That's where my understanding is unclear.

For the problem I'm solving, just using the binary will work fine.

But I'm curious, if I did want to use the `go run` process - how would I close it properly?

Repro for this here: [GitHub](https://github.com/dwjohnston/node-and-go-child-process).

Comment: This delves into the realms of process supervision, as `go run` appears to [not play nicely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54013010/how-do-i-send-a-signal-to-a-child-process). What operating systems do you want this to work on?

Comment: Ultimately macos and linux. (The real world use case is that I want to run a server from my node process and run tests against it, this would want to occur on both devs machines, as well as build servers). It's nice to know that this approach might encounter OS specific issues.

Comment: @Matt But yeah, I guess I would like the high level overview of process supervision, I would have hoped that a child process can't spawn processes that makes its parent can't control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `go run` command builds the executable and then runs the executable in the background waiting for it. Which means that the process ID of `go run` is different than the PID of the executable.

You can use the `-exec` to tell `go run` to run another program (not `go`).
For example, you can write `run.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

# Run executable in background
$1&

# $! is child pid
echo PID: $!

# Wait for child to end
wait $!
```

And then execute `go run -exec /path/to/run.sh main.go`
Tried this with the following `main.go`:
package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(os.Getpid())
}
```

And got:

```
$ go run -exec /tmp/run.sh /tmp/main.go
PID: 13679
13679
```

In your node code you'll have to parse the output to get the PID.

Comment: Any suggestions for, in the abstract, if you are creating a process from node, and that process may create a background process like we have in the initial question, how you could shut them all down from the parent process? Or is this simply a 'that's not possible scenario'?

Comment: You can build to a temporary file and then run it instead of `go run`. It's one more command to execute but makes things simpler (that's when I do in tests).

You might want to try and kill the `go run` process group ID, not sure if it'll work. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392022/whats-the-best-way-to-send-a-signal-to-all-members-of-a-process-group